# NumberOfConcurrentThreads parameter in CreateIoCompletionPort

Tags: network-programming, winsock, winsock2, iocp

I am **still** confused about the `NumberOfConcurrentThreads` parameter within `CreateIoCompletionPort()`.  I have read and re-read the [MSDN dox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), but the quote

> This value limits the number of runnable threads associated with the
>   completion port.

still puzzles me.

**Question**

Let's assume that I specify this value as 4.  In this case, does this mean that:

1) a thread can call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` (at which point I can allow a further 3 threads to make this call), then as soon as that call returns (i.e. we have a completion packet) I can then have 4 threads again call this function,

**or**

2) a thread can call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` (at which point I can allow a further 3 threads to make this call), then as soon as that call returns (i.e. we have a completion packet) I then go on to process that packet.  Only when I have finished processing the packet do I then call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`, at which point I can **then** have 4 threads again call this function.

See my confusion?  Its the use of the phrase 'runnable threads'.

I think it might be the latter, because the link above also quotes

> *If your transaction required a lengthy computation*, a larger
>   concurrency value will allow more threads to run. Each completion
>   packet may take longer to finish, but more completion packets will be
>   processed at the same time.

This will ultimately affect how we design servers.  Consider a server that receives data from clients, then echoes that data to logging servers.  Here is what our thread routine could look like:

```
DWORD WINAPI ServerWorkerThread(HANDLE hCompletionPort)
{
    DWORD BytesTransferred;
    CPerHandleData* PerHandleData = nullptr;
    CPerOperationData* PerIoData = nullptr;

    while (TRUE)
    {
        if (GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hCompletionPort, &BytesTransferred,
            (PULONG_PTR)&PerHandleData, (LPOVERLAPPED*)&PerIoData, INFINITE))
        {
            // OK, we have 'BytesTransferred' of data in 'PerIoData', process it:
            // send the data onto our logging servers, then loop back around
            send(...);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now assume I have a four core machine; if I leave `NumberOfConcurrentThreads` as zero within my call to `CreateIoCompletionPort()` I will have four threads running `ServerWorkerThread()`.  Fine.

My concern is that the `send()` call may take a long time due to network traffic.  Hence, I could be receiving a load of data from clients that cannot be dequeued because all four threads are taking a long time sending the data on?!

Have I missed the point here?

**Update 07.03.2018** **(This has now been resolved: see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138358/numberofconcurrentthreads-parameter-in-createiocompletionport#comment85317826_49139525).)**

I have 8 threads running on my machine, each one runs the `ServerWorkerThread()`:

```
DWORD WINAPI ServerWorkerThread(HANDLE hCompletionPort)
{
DWORD BytesTransferred;
CPerHandleData* PerHandleData = nullptr;
CPerOperationData* PerIoData = nullptr;

while (TRUE)
{
    if (GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hCompletionPort, &BytesTransferred,
        (PULONG_PTR)&PerHandleData, (LPOVERLAPPED*)&PerIoData, INFINITE))
    {
    switch (PerIoData->Operation)
    {
    case  CPerOperationData::ACCEPT_COMPLETED:
    {
        // This case is fired when a new connection is made
        while (1) {}
    }
}
}
```

I only have one outstanding `AcceptEx()` call; when that gets filled by a new connection I post another one.  I don't wait for data to be received in `AcceptEx()`.

I create my completion port as follows:

```
CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 4)
```

Now, because I only allow 4 threads in the completion port, I thought that **because I keep the threads busy** (i.e. they do not enter a wait state), when I try and make a fifth connection, the completion packet would not be dequeued hence would hang!  However this is not the case; I can make 5 or even 6 connections to my server!  This shows that I can still dequeue packets even though my maximum allowed number of threads (4) are already running?  *This is why I am confused!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the completion port - is really [`KQUEUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-keinitializequeue) object. the *NumberOfConcurrentThreads* is corresponded to `MaximumCount`

> Maximum number of concurrent threads the queue can satisfy waits for.

from I/O Completion Ports

> When the total number of runnable threads associated with the
>   completion port reaches the concurrency value, **the system blocks the
>   execution of any subsequent threads** associated with that completion
>   port until the number of runnable threads drops below the concurrency
>   value.

it's bad and not exactly said. when thread call [`KeRemoveQueue`](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/ke/queueobj.c#L258) ( `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` internal call it) system return packet to thread [only if](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/ke/queueobj.c#L391) `Queue->CurrentCount < Queue->MaximumCount` even if exist packets in queue. system **not blocks** any threads of course. from another side look for [`KiInsertQueue`](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/ke/queueobj.c#L656) - even if some threads wait on packets - it activated only in case [`Queue->CurrentCount < Queue->MaximumCount`](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/ke/queueobj.c#L714).

also look how and when `Queue->CurrentCount` is changed. look for [`KiActivateWaiterQueue`](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/ke/ki.h#L1821) (*This function is called when the current thread is about to enter a wait state*) and [`KiUnlinkThread`](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/ke/ki.h#L3046). in general - when thread begin wait for any object (or another queue) system call [`KiActivateWaiterQueue`](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/ke/ki.h#L1821) - it decrement `CurrentCount` and possible (if exist packets in queue and became `Queue->CurrentCount < Queue->MaximumCount` and threads waited for packets) return packet to wait thread. from another side, when thread stop wait - [`KiUnlinkThread`](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/ke/ki.h#L3046) is called. it increment `CurrentCount`.

your both variant is wrong. any count of threads can call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`. and system of course not blocks the execution of any subsequent threads. for example - you have queue with `MaximumCount = 4`. you can queue 10 packets to queue. and call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` from 7 threads in concurrent. but only 4 from it got packets. another will be wait (despite yet 6 packets in queue). if some of threads, which remove packet from queue begin wait - system just unwait and return packet to another thread wait on queue. or if thread (which already previous remove packet from this queue (`Thread->Queue == Queue`) - so active thread) again call `KeRemoveQueue` will be [`Queue->CurrentCount -= 1;`](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/ke/queueobj.c#L369)

Comment: Thanks for the background. However I am still confused.. Sorry. Can you please specifically address my two questions?

Comment: @Wad - but I reply to your first question - try describe how `NumberOfConcurrentThreads` is work. what is unclear here ?

Comment: OK.  I have edited my question to clarify what I am concerned about.  Can you please comment on that new edit?  Please see "Update 07.03.2018" section.  Thanks!

Comment: @Wad - dont know - you must not got such result. print verbose log with thread id which got `CPerOperationData::ACCEPT_COMPLETED`. simply example for test - https://pastebin.com/2pnwmd8d

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet.  I figured out what I was doing wrong; I was letting the debugger break into the code at the point of hitting the infinite loop; this must have caused enough of a "wait" to allow the system to let another packet be dequeued.  When I have no breakpoints, I cannot have more than 4 threads enter the infinite loop.

Comment: Can you just confirm that if I allow 4threads (or any number via `NumberOfConcurrentThreads`) to be in the IOCP, I can only dequeue another packet (do more work) when one of those threads enters a wait state OR when it completes its work and calls `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` to get another packet (if there is one)?  In other words, Windows judges a threads to be "runnable" if it has called `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` and a) hasn't entered a wait state and b) hasn't called `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` a second time (i.e. is still processing the first packet it dequeued)? Is this correct?

Comment: @Wad - yes. again - look yourself for [`KeRemoveQueue`](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/ke/queueobj.c#L258) code. or take - my code snippet - change 1 to 2 in `CreateIoCompletionPort` and look how log changed. at all you can easy change thread count (`HANDLE hThreads[N]) and *NumberOfConcurrentThreads* - and look for result in log

Comment: Thank you.  I have added a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49172724/2369597), please take a look if you could!