# IO Completion ports: separate thread pool to process the dequeued packets?

Tags: c++11, network-programming, winsock, winsock2, iocp

**NOTE**: I have added the C++ tag to this because a) the code is C++ and b) people using C++ may well have used IO completion ports.  So please don't shout.

---

I am playing with IO completion ports, and have eventually fully understood (and tested, to prove) - both with help from [RbMm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6401656/rbmm) - the meaning of the `NumberOfConcurrentThreads` parameter within `CreateIoCompletionPort()`.

I have the following small program which creates 10 threads all waiting on the completion port.  I tell my completion port to only allow 4 threads to be runnable at once (I have four CPUs).  I then enqueue 8 packets to the port.  My thread function outputs a message if it dequeues a packet with an ID > 4; in order for this message to be output, I have to stop at least one of the four currently running threads, which happens when I enter '1' at the console.

Now this is all fairly simple code.  I have one big concern however, and that is that **if all of the threads that are processing a completion packet get bogged down, it will mean no more packets can be dequeued and processed**.  *That is what I am simulating with my infinite loop* - the fact that no more packets are dequeued until I enter '1' at the console highlights this potential problem!

Would a better solution not be to have my four threads dequeuing packets (or as many threads as CPUs), then when one is dequeued, farm the processing of that packet off to a worker thread *from a separate pool*, thereby removing the risk of all threads in the IOCP being bogged down thus no more packets being dequeued?

I ask this as **all** the examples of IO completion port code I have seen use a method similar to what I show below, *not* using a separate thread pool which I propose.  This is what makes me think that **I** am missing something because I am outnumbered!

Note: this is a somewhat contrived example, because [Windows will allow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx) an additional packet to be dequeued if one of the runnable threads enters a wait state; I show this in my code with a commented out `cout` call:

> The system also allows a thread waiting in GetQueuedCompletionStatus
>   to process a completion packet if another running thread associated
>   with the same I/O completion port enters a wait state for other
>   reasons, for example the SuspendThread function. When the thread in
>   the wait state begins running again, there may be a brief period when
>   the number of active threads exceeds the concurrency value. **However,
>   the system quickly reduces this number by not allowing any new active
>   threads until the number of active threads falls below the concurrency
>   value**.

But I won't be calling `SuspendThread` in my thread functions, a*nd I don't know which functions other than `cout` will cause the thread to enter a wait state*, thus I can't predict if one or more of my threads will ever get bogged down!  Hence my idea of a thread pool; at least context switching would mean that other packets get a chance to be dequeued!

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <atomic>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HANDLE hCompletionPort1;
    if ((hCompletionPort1 = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 4)) == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    vector<thread> vecAllThreads;
    atomic_bool bStop(false);

    // Fill our vector with 10 threads, each of which waits on our IOCP.
    generate_n(back_inserter(vecAllThreads), 10, [hCompletionPort1, &bStop] {
        thread t([hCompletionPort1, &bStop]()
        {
            // Thread body
            while (true)
            {
                DWORD dwBytes = 0;
                LPOVERLAPPED pOverlapped = 0;
                ULONG_PTR uKey;
                if (::GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hCompletionPort1, &dwBytes, &uKey, &pOverlapped, INFINITE) == 1)
                {
                    if (dwBytes == 0 && uKey == 0 && pOverlapped == 0)
                        break;  // Special completion packet; end processing.

                    //cout << uKey; // EVEN THIS WILL CAUSE A "wait" which causes MORE THAN 4 THREADS TO ENTER!

                    if (uKey >4) 
                        cout << "Started processing packet ID > 4!" << endl;
                    while (!bStop)
                        ;   // INFINITE LOOP
                }
            }
        });
        return move(t);
    }
    );

    // Queue 8 completion packets to our IOCP...only four will be processed until we set our bool
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; ++i)
    {
        PostQueuedCompletionStatus(hCompletionPort1, 0, i, new OVERLAPPED);
    }

    while (!bStop)
    {
        int nVal;
        cout << "Enter 1 to cause current processing threads to end: ";
        cin >> nVal;
        bStop = (nVal == 1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)    // Tell all 10 threads to stop processing on the IOCP
    {
        PostQueuedCompletionStatus(hCompletionPort1, 0, 0, 0);  // Special packet marking end of IOCP usage
    }
    for_each(begin(vecAllThreads), end(vecAllThreads), mem_fn(&thread::join));

    return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT #1**

What I mean by "separate thread pool" is something like the following:

```
class myThread {
public:
    void SetTask(LPOVERLAPPED pO) { /* start processing pO*/ }
private:
    thread m_thread;    // Actual thread object
};

// The threads in this thread pool are not associated with the IOCP in any way whatsoever; they exist
// purely to be handed a completion packet which they then process!
class ThreadPool
{
public:
    void Initialise() { /* create 100 worker threads and add them to some internal storage*/}
    myThread& GetNextFreeThread() { /* return one of the 100 worker thread we created*/}
} g_threadPool;
```

The code that each of my four threads associated with the IOCP then change to

```
if (::GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hCompletionPort1, &dwBytes, &uKey, &pOverlapped, INFINITE) == 1)
{
    if (dwBytes == 0 && uKey == 0 && pOverlapped == 0)
        break;  // Special completion packet; end processing.

    // Pick a new thread from a pool of pre-created threads and assign it the packet to process
    myThread& thr = g_threadPool.GetNextFreeThread();
    thr.SetTask(pOverlapped);

    // Now, this thread can immediately return to the IOCP; it doesn't matter if the
    // packet we dequeued would take forever to process; that is happening in the 
    // separate thread thr *that will not intefere with packets being dequeued from IOCP!*
}
```

This way, there is no possible way that I can end up in the situation where no more packets are being dequeued!

Comment: in general the number of threads in pool which de-queue from some *iocp* must be exactly *NumberOfConcurrentThreads* parameter within `CreateIoCompletionPort`. you must process item fast or asynchronous. and not need use separate thread pool - this is senseless - reinsert same item to another iocp

Comment: not need special suspend thread or do other not native tricks

Comment: Right, that contradicts the MSDN dox I linked to which states *...but a good rule of thumb is to have a minimum of twice as many threads in the thread pool as there are processors on the system.*  My concern is that I might not be able to process the data quickly; I'm not talking about a simple echo server I'm talking about something which could do a lot of complex processing on each packet it receives...this is why I think a separate thread pool is a better choice??

Comment: Also what do you mean by *reinsert same item to another iocp*?  Are you saying I should dequeue a packet then pass it to another IOCP? W hat would that achieve?

Comment: *My concern is that I might not be able to process the data quickly* - use in general asynchronous processing in this case. if you can not do this (really in most case this is possible)- you can have and more threads in pool. but only in case you really use long processing.

Comment: *worker thread from a separate pool* - this i mean - not big sense use

Comment: OK I have updated the question with an example of what I mean by "thread pool"...please see "EDIT #1".  Can you please comment?

Comment: i think you on wrong way. you not need separate additional thread pool - for what ? if you redirect task to it - what will be benefit. of course not need 100 worked threads. need use asynchronous processing

Comment: OK.  In my small example, I post 8 packets.  Because the 'processing' of those packets is complicated (my 'infinite loop'), all 4 threads are  busy processing the first 4 packets, hence Windows will not allow any more threads to dequeue another completion packet.  So packets 5 - 8 are sitting waiting to be dequeued.Now, instead, if, after dequeuing those first 4 packets, I handed the processing of each of them to another separate thread (four threads total, one per packet), it would mean that packets 5-8 could be dequeued immediately and also handed off to a separate thread.  Can you see this?

Comment: I think you should take a look at the CreateThreadpoolIO API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682464(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks; I will look at that.  Can you comment on my last comment please?

Comment: shortly said separate thread pool senseless here. if you can not avoid long packet processing - simply use more threads in current pool. what benefit for move packet to another pool ? only degrade performance. faster "move" threads to original pool. if you will be have some problems with original pool - you will be the same problems in separate  - what different from which pool you pop packet ? but real solution - this is asynchronous processing. avoid long operations and wait in pool - this is quit possible

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me on this.I have shown in my original code that if the processing of a dequeued packet takes a long time, and that thread **is never put into a wait state** then it is possible that all the threads that are responsible for dequeuing packets (4 here) could eventually be occupied processing the packets.  Then, how will I dequeue more packets?  It doesn't matter how many threads are in my pool if I only allow as many threads as there are CPUs to be in the IOCP (4 in my case) - Windows won't allow any more to run (as we've discussed) until one enters a wait state!

Comment: Are you saying then that the chances of a thread becoming fully occupied (i.e. never entering the "wait" state) are very small?  because if this is the case, then I can see your point...

Comment: Hi, sorry but could you possibly comment on my last comments so I can close this question?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is conflicting opinion on whether a separate thread pool should be used.  Clearly, as the sample code I have posted shows, there is potential for packets to stop being dequeued from the IOCP if the processing of the packets does not enter a wait state; given, the infinite loop is perhaps unrealistic but it does demonstrate the point.

Comment: infinite loop is unrealistic. other than that for example for long running tasks, it means cpu has got something to do useful. if you are concerned about better multitasking-responsiveness-fairness threadpool will behave same and you have to implement some kind of scheduling alghoritm by yourself